# Java: how to get mercurial current changeset number for use in program

Tags: java, mercurial, changeset

I've recently started using mercurial for version control in a Java project. When I run my program, the input parameters it has used to produce certain a output, are written to a specific file. It would be nice if I could add the current mercurial changeset number (indicating the version of my program) to that output file as well.

What would be the easiest way to do so on Windows? 
I could write a simple Java parser to fetch the output of the first line of the `hg log -l 1`  command, but perhaps there is an easier way (i.e., less code lines)?

Answer (score 10):

You can rather use **[`hg identify`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#identify)**.

`hg id` should be during the packaging step, when the sources have been committed and you generate the packaged (jar) version of your application.
During that step, you can generate a version.txt file with that kind of information.

```
$ MY_VERSION=$(hg id)
$ echo $MY_VERSION
53efa13dec6f+ tip
```

(see for instance ["build identification" for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0385/#build-identification))

Comment: That trailing plus sign means VonC has local, uncommitted changes, which can be nice to note too.

Comment: Speaking of which, how is that migration coming along?

Comment: you mean hg identify; and a downside is that it shows the short human readable hash rather than the full 40 character sha1

Answer (score 7):

Since you're in a Java project, this might be relevant to you. I use this Ant target to display the version info (Mercurial changeset id) in the application list in the Tomcat Manager page. I simply put the changeset id inside the *display-name* xml element in my web.xml.

```
<target name="build.release">
    <exec executable="/usr/local/bin/hg" outputproperty="scm.version.tag.id">
        <arg value="id"/>
        <arg value="-i"/>
    </exec>
    <filter token="build.version.tag" value="${scm.version.tag.id}" />
    <copy file="${web.home}/WEB-INF/web.xml" todir="${build.home}" filtering="true" />
</target>
```

Inside the web.xml, there's a token in the *display-name* xml element, like this:

```
<display-name>My Webapp @build.version.tag@</display-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the view of the Mercurial developers: [Keyword Substitution - Why You Don't Need It](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordPlan)

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the point. What is meant by keyword expansion? The only thing I can think of is e.g. that you can write 'hg id' instead of 'hg identity', but that concept doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: Other VCS allow you to add special keywords such as $Id$, $Rev$, $Author$ that are expanded when the file is checked out. This allowed you to write things like const char * version = "$Rev$"; which would become something like const char * version = "$Rev: 1.2$" when the file was checked out.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial has an extension for keyword expansion. See [KeywordExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension) for instructions and warnings.

Comment: That's pretty nice.  I'm assuming that each file gets info from the most recent commit that actually changed the individual file?  (and yes, I *DO* need keyword expansion, if I want to track what other people are inadvertently doing (changes entirely outside of revision control aside, alas).  Only when your release system is actually being followed correctly does the need for supplemental info like keywords go away.

Comment: This is mapped as "feature of last resort" and should rather not be used

Answer (score 2):

hg branch | xargs hg log -l1 --template {rev} -b

This will give you the revision number for the current branch that you are working in - very important for builds from different branches.

In an ant file this is what you need...

```
    <exec dir="${basedir}"
        executable="/usr/local/bin/hg"
        outputproperty="branch">

          <arg value="branch"/>
    </exec>

    <exec dir="${basedir}"
          executable="/usr/local/bin/hg"
          outputproperty="version">

          <arg value="log"/>
          <arg line="-l1 --template {rev} -b${branch}" />
    </exec>
```