# What is the plus sign after revision number in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We are using Mercurial and TortoiseHg at work and I always see `+` sign after my working directory revision number and Google doesn't tell me anything about it. Is there any one who can explain this?

Here is a snapshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the answer?

Comment: @melpomene: that is indeed correct

Comment: @melpomene : Could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it? Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google tells me it means you have uncommitted local changes in your repository.

See also [Java: how to get mercurial current changeset number for use in program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805976/java-how-to-get-mercurial-current-changeset-number-for-use-in-program#comment2846011_2806080), https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301105/1848654, and http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/01/21/assembly-versioning-with-hg.

Comment: If you run hg id it will also append the + suffix. THG seems to inherited the notation from there